# Add Event-Listener for the whole Symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox, addeventlistener

I´ve put a Label and a ComboBox together in a Symbol, like in the code below.

```
public class LabelCombo extends MovieClip {     


        //myLabel is an instance of fl.controls.Label
        //myCombo is an instance of fl.controls.ComboBox
        public function LabelCombo() {              
        }


        public function setLabelText(s:String):void{
            myLabel.text = s;
        }

        public function getLabelText():String{
            return myLabel.text;
        }



        public function removeAllItems():void{
            if(myCombo.dataProvider.length > 0)
                myCombo.removeAll();
        }


        public function setSingleItem(o:Object):void{
            removeAllItems();
            myCombo.addItem(o);
        }


        public function setList(itemList:Array):void{
            for(var i:int = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
                if(i==0)
                    setSingleItem(itemList[i]);
                else
                    addSingleItem(itemList[i]);
            }
        }


        public function addSingleItem(o:Object):void{
            for(var i:int = 0; i < myCombo.dataProvider.length; i++){
                    if(o == myCombo.getItemAt(i))
                        return;
                }
            myCombo.addItem(o);
        }


        public function addList(itemList:Array):void{
            for(var i:int = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
                addSingleItem(itemList[i]);
            }
        }

        public function getSelectedItem():Object{
            return myCombo.selectedItem;
        }

        public function getItemByLabel(s:String):Object{
            return Object(myCombo.getChildByName(s));
        }

        public function selectItemAt(index:int):void{
            myCombo.selectedIndex = index;
        }

        public function getselectedIndex():int{
            return myCombo.selectedIndex;
        }

    }
```

Now I want to `addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler)`
on the whole Symbol so I can do something like that

`trace(LabelCombo(event.currentTarget).getLabelText())`

`trace(LabelCombo(event.currentTarget).getSelectedItem().data)`

I need information from both single controls.
It`d be nice if someone can show me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I´ve recognized that there are some misunderstandings:
I need this for a communication via XMLSocket. The server has to know two things: 1) what is the name of the ComboBox (in this case I get the name with myLabel) 2) the new selected Index
Hope now everything is much clearer

Comment: ...and you are expecting first trace to show you `myLabel.text` is that right? Why does it have to be an event setup? Why can't it just be applied to string and then you trace that string to check what you've got. That would be best way... Or do you have bigger plans with this events version?

Comment: you need to add eventlistener to object of LabelCombo ?

Comment: When you need your `Event.CHANGE` event to be fired ? When values are changed or ( for combobox ) when selected value is changed ? In all cases, you have just to dispatch your event in these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand you question but you could try this

```
public class LabelCombo extends MovieClip {     
        //myLabel is an instance of fl.controls.Label
        //myCombo is an instance of fl.controls.ComboBox
        public function LabelCombo() { 
              myLabel.addEventlistener(Event.CHANGE,onChange);
              myCombo.addEventlistener(Event.CHANGE,onChange);

        }
        private function onChange(e:Event):void {
             dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        } 
        }
```

add change event listeners to the label and combo. Using dispatchEvent you could dispatch custom event .
You could use like this

```
var labeCombo:LabelCombo = new LabelCombo();
addChild(labeCombo);
labeCombo.addEventlistener(Event.CHANGE,onChangeMv);
function onChangeMv(e:Event){
    trace(labeCombo.getLabelText());
    trace(labeCombo.getSelectedItem().data);
}
```

You can use custome event class to send data along with the event dispatcher.

Comment: +1 I know my english and my description is not the best one, but you have written exactly the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You just set the event listener to `myCombo` but the listener should be located in the code of `LabelCombo`, this way you won't need tricks with `event.currentTarget` and just use `this` context to work with children, as the listener will only be triggered by changes in this object's `myCombo` child.

```
myCombo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onChange,false,0,true);
function onChange(e:Event):void {
    trace(getSelectedItem().data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I meant was instead of this:

```
trace(LabelCombo(event.currentTarget).getLabelText())
```

try like this: (if possible)

```
LabelCombo.setLabelText("Just_A_Test");
var str_Check : String = LabelCombo.getLabelText();
trace ("returned string is : " + str_Check);
```

It should say `returned string is : Just_A_Test`...

If **LabelCombo** is a child of **myCombo** then the correct reference path is: `myCombo.LabelCombo.getLabelText();` etc etc.